# Scheduling CPU Bound and Interactive Tasks in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, scheduler

I've been taking a course about operating systems on Udacity. The lecturer mentioned that priority level of CPU bound tasks in Linux(I assume same for most OS's) are lower than the priority level of interactive tasks which causes CPU bound tasks to have smaller time slices on CPU.

---

I know that it's good to start interactive tasks earlier since they might ask for an I/O operation and CPU can be utilized by other processes while waiting I/O operations to be completed. However what is the reason for giving higher timeslices since they already will be waiting for an operation and will be put to I/O waiting queue. On the other hand giving small time slices to CPU bound tasks will result in lots of context switches since they wouldn't be able to complete the task at once. So what is the logic behind it that I couldn't understand ? Thank you.

Comment: Re, "lots of context switches..." Not necessarily true.  If a compute-bound thread gets interrupted at the end of its time slice, but then is immediately granted a new one because no other thread is waiting to run, then that probably does not count as a "context switch".

Comment: Actually that makes sense. Ok given that it won't take some extra time but why they give extra time slice to user interactive tasks in the first place ? What makes their computation more important than CPU bound tasks?

Comment: If you're the administrator of a Linux system or some other desktop/server operating system, you probably can choose between any of several different _[scheduling disciplines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Scheduling_disciplines)_.  Those are algorithms that fiddle with the true scheduling priorities, time-slice lengths, and etc. of processes in order to achieve some level of fairness and/or some performance targets.  It's not an area where I have any experience, but I understand that one has to make certain compromises.

Comment: @jameslarge I have read in a different site that in general OS's priority is in the favor of the user which is interacting with the computer so in behalf of not to reflect any latency to the user they compromise from bare computation. Like you said every choice has ups and downs. Thank you for the answer.